# Correlating an Android AImage generated by AMediaCodec with output buffer

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm working on an application which decodes a h265 stream into a texture.

I use the AImageReader_setImageListener callback to retrieve an AImage, which I can then fetch a hardware buffer to the decoded images with, but am looking for a way to correlate theis with information about the output buffer, specifically looking to get the info in AMediaCodecBufferInfo.

I can't seem to find any functions that will correlate the AImage with the output buffer from the media codec (but maybe I missed something), so have been wondering what the ideal way would be to correlate these is?